# RxJava delayed observables fire with unexpected delays

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have an event sequence set up using RxJava observables. Basically I merge different events created with `Observable.just(Events.*)` with different delays set up with `observable.delay(time, timeUnit, scheduler)` function. Then I post them to a `PublishSubject` (`events` in the code below) and subscribe to that `PublishSubject` to observe the sequence (`observeEvents()` function in the code below). It used to work fine but recently I'm seeing a very weird behaviour on my device (OnePlus One with android 5.0.2) (and don't see it on emulator). Basically the events get mixed up, events with higher delay can come before events with smaller delay, events with small delay can come at the end of the queue, sometimes all events might come in right order. The first 3 events are mixed especially often. Sometimes some event are not observed at all. What could be happening here?

The code is in Kotlin:

```
var computationScheduler = Schedulers.computation()

private val events: PublishSubject<Events> = PublishSubject.create()
private val userActionSubject: PublishSubject<Events> = PublishSubject.create()

Observable.merge(
            event0(),
            event1(),
            event2(),
            userActionOrEvent3(),
            userActionOrEvent4())
            .subscribe({
                // Weird timings are observed here already
                events.onNext(it)
            }, { e ->
                events.onError(e)
            }))

private fun userActionOrEvent4(): Observable<Events> {
    return Observable.amb(Observable.just(Events.Event4)
            .delay(12800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, computationScheduler), userActionSubject.asObservable().subscribeOn(computationScheduler))
            .take(1)
}

private fun userActionOrEvent3(): Observable<Events> {
    return Observable.amb(Observable.just(Events.Event3)
            .delay(2800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, computationScheduler), userActionSubject.asObservable().subscribeOn(computationScheduler))
            .take(1)
}

private fun event2() = Observable.just(Events.Event2)
        .delay(1800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, computationScheduler)

private fun event1() = Observable.just(Events.Event1)
        .delay(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, computationScheduler)

private fun event0() = Observable.just(Events.Event0)
        .subscribeOn(computationScheduler)

open fun observeEvents(): Observable<Events> = events.asObservable().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

open fun onUserAction() {
    userActionSubject.onNext(Events.Action)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the problem was caused by computationScheduler, when I changed `Schedulers.computation()` to `Schedulers.newThread()` events started to fire at expected timings.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using `merge()` rather than a `concat`

This medium article will explain to you the difference https://medium.com/fueled-android/rxify-a-simple-spell-for-complex-rxjava-operators-part-2-b82b379f5c7f#.ekppat50o